# How do I create dynamic html which has value with single quote in EJS (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL)

Tags: jquery, ejs

I want to add dynamically created `select` to a div. I am using EJS. My table 'course' has course name as "Bachelor's in commerce" or "Bachelor's in comp". How do I handle it? I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error in console. Here is my code.

```
 var collegehtml ='';
 collegehtml +='<select name="course" >';
 collegehtml += "<% for (var j = 0; j < course.length; j++){ %>"
 collegehtml += '<option value="<%= course[j].ID %>">';
 collegehtml += "<%= course[j].Name %>";// error is thrown on this line
 collegehtml += "</option>";
 collegehtml += "<% } %>";
 collegehtml += "</select>";
 $("#addcourse").html(collegehtml);
```

Comment: <select> is not closed while creating.

Comment: It is closed in my code. Updating my code on SO. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Where / which line you have this error?

Comment: collegehtml += "<%= course[j].Name %>";

Comment: try to replace option's three lines with this    collegehtml += '<option value="<%= course[j].ID %>">'+<%= course[j].Name %>+'</option>';

Comment: I had tried that too, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you should escape it from Node, with a function like [this](https://github.com/component/escape-html). I don't have EJS or node installed, but I see two ways:

- `collegehtml += "<%= escapeHtml(course[j].Name) %>";`, if calling functions from the template works

or

- just do `course[j].Name = escapeHtml(course[j].Name)` in the back end code, before reaching the template's output

Hope it helps and I don't have it all wrong. :)

Comment: still no luck, now i doubt about the exact issue. Is it due to single quote or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this block for `<option>`

```
            <%
               for (var j = 0; j < course.length; j++){
                    %><option value="<%= course[j].ID %>"><%= course[j].Name %><%
                }
            %>
```